# How can i do a validate if a person has uploaded a file

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I am getting this error message.

> javax.validation.UnexpectedTypeException: HV000030: No validator could
>   be found for type: byte[].

The code is

```
@NotBlank(message = DocumentForm.NOT_BLANK_MESSAGE)
private byte[] file;
```

How can i do a validate if a person has uploaded a file

Comment: You may find this useful if venturing into custom validation: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.0.1/reference/en-US/pdf/hibernate_reference.pdf

Answer (score 2):

`@NotBlank` is for Strings. It's also not part of the standard for that matter. You probably want to go with `@NotNull`. It only checks if a file is there, though, not if it's empty. If that's necessary as well you can use `@Size(min = 1)`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what annotations are available for a byte array, if any. However, you could implement your own validator without much trouble.

Something like:

```
public class ModelWithFileFieldValidator implements Validator {

    public boolean supports(Class clazz) {
        return ModelWithFileField.class.equals(clazz);
    }

    public void validate(Object obj, Errors e) {
        byte[] field = ((ModelWithFileField)obj).getBytes();
        if (field == null || field.length == 0) {
            e.rejectValue("file", "empty");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice NullPointerException ^^

Answer (score 1):

It can be done by using @NotEmpty.
It is a combination of @NotNull and size/length > 0

@NotEmpty = @NotNull &&  size/length > 0

```
@NotEmpty(message = DocumentForm.NOT_BLANK_MESSAGE)
private byte[] file;
```

https://www.baeldung.com/java-bean-validation-not-null-empty-blank